# Swift : protocol extension and arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, protocols

I have some struct objects that are heterogeneous like this

```
struct Cat: Hashable {
   let name: String
   let catId: Int
}
struct SubCat: Hashable {
   let name: String
   let catId: Int
   let parentCatId: Int
}
```

Now I have a tableView that needs to show either Cat or SubCat. My first choice was to extend both classes with a protocol :

```
protocol Selectable {
    func asString() -> String
}
```

and my struct became :

```
struct Cat: Hashable, Selectable {
   let name: String
   let catId: Int
   func asString() -> {
      return self.name
  }
}
struct SubCat: Hashable, Selectable {
   let name: String
   let catId: Int
   let parentCatId: Int
   func asString() -> {
      return self.name
  }
}
```

It worked so far.
I declared a [Selectable] object in my TableViewController, used asString() to populate my cells. Compiled like a charm.

But here's the thing. I've got a CatModel class and a SubCatModel class, each returning an array of each structs [Cats] and [SubCats]
When I try to assign the [Cat] array to the [Selectable] array, it does not compile. If I changed the return type of my [Cat] array to [Selectable], it does not compile.

Can anyone help me with this? I guess I'm missing something here.
Thanks.

Comment: i think you had to cast it when you set your array, by testing protocol. like this:

`if let selectableArray = catArray as? Selectable { }`

let me know if it helps you

Comment: I already tried. The compiler says that Selectable  is not a subtype of Cat :-/

Comment: Oh yes, cat is a struct, maybe by creating it like Class instead ?

Comment: A very similar issue was observed (and considered as a *bug*) here: http://inessential.com/2015/08/02/swift_diary_7_protocols_arrays_and_c.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, it worked well ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map `Cat` array to `Selectable` array:

```
let selectableArray = catArray.map { $0 as Selectable }
```

Comment: Thanks :) As Martin R. said, it worked like a charm!